# How to efficiently sort a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries in Python and I want to sort this list based on a specific key in the dictionaries. The list is quite large, so I'm looking for an efficient way to do this.

I've tried using the `sorted` function with a lambda function as the key, like this:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x['my_key'])
```

This works, but it seems to be quite slow with large lists.

Comment: `sorted` is O(n lg n) with good constants. It's not clear what you consider "quite slow". You might try `key=itemgetter('my_key')`, which should be a little faster than calling a user-defined function. (The key function is only called O(n) times, though, so it's probably not a big bottleneck in the overall sorting time.)

Comment: `sorted` uses [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) and this sorting algorithm is known to be very fast with real world data. I'm afraid there's not much performance to gain.

Comment: If you want something better than that, you need to tell us more about your data.

Answer (score 2):

To deal with larger datasets, using itemgetter could be more efficient and faster than lambda functions.
You can try writing this code-

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter('my_key'))
```